# I am struggling with text on a header image especially in mobile view

Tags: header

I have made a header on my home page using css and have a container for the text. It works apart from when I go to mobile view.. the writing is then no longer in the header. i thought it was just a missing  but when i put it in it is still happening

```
 .image-container {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/bannerbackground.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  }

<main>
 <body>
  <div class="banner">
   <div class="image-container"></div>
    <div class=header>
   <div class="centered">
    <h1><i>Alexia Lockhart <br><br>
        <h2>Author of Nobody's Hero and The Wildflower Series</h2>
      </i></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```